# Problem with normal map ans smooth shading

Tags: shaders, lighting, normal-map

When I use normal map shading on part of my handle doesn't have smooth shading.[image]

[image][image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see the problem, can you circle the problem area in your reference image?

Comment: Normal map strength of 2 is extreme, try something below .5

Comment: @Nascent Space If you  look at the handle on engraving part you can see it.

Comment: @AllenSimpson it helps a little bit but not enough

Comment: Is there a duplicate mesh intersecting with the bottom of the handle?

Comment: @AllenSimpson no

Comment: If this is a high-to-low baked normal map, or if it was made in something like SP, you want the normal map to have a strength of 1.0 and nothing else.  The normal map contains the difference between the low poly and high poly normals, and setting it to anything other than 1.0 will show you differences between the two that you didn't want to show.

Comment: @Nathan As a said changing it to 1 didn't change much

Comment: @Zinek Then think about linking a file, with packed images.  Preferably, demonstrating exactly how the normal map was created as well (high poly?)

Comment: @Nathan I've just found the problem, my model had no uniform scale.